# IE7 (IE8 Compatability Mode) bug: crazy amound of width applied to a floated element that is parent to another float

Tags: internet-explorer-7, nested, css-float

Here's my problem.  It looks perfect in Firefox, Safari, IE8, but in IE7 and IE8 comparability mode, it adds about 4000px of width to the div.team elements nested within the list item. the problem goes away if i remove the span.score elements.

The image attached shows the score in the first box in white number text.  The top image is the way it's supposed to look. The bottom is IE7.

[image: normal browser]

[image: IE7]

I've been trying to figure this out for hours.  I even tried making the list a bunch of divs in case it was a weird IE7 list item bug, but I got the exact same results.

Here's my html:

```
    <ul class="selected" data-league="ncaaf">
        <li>
            <div class="time">THU 12:30PM</div>
            <div class="teams">
                <div class="team">AUB (21) <span class="score">10</span></div>
                <div class="team">MSST <span class="score">22</span></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        ...
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.boxList ul {
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    heigth:40px;
    width:5000px;
    clear:left;
    display:none;
}
.boxList ul.selected {
    display:block;  
}

.boxList li {
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    padding:0 5px;
    min-width:56px;
    background:url(../images/scoreSchedBoxTile.png) repeat-x;
    border:1px solid #000;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    font-size:9px;
    line-height:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}

    .boxList li .time {
        text-align:center;  
    }
    .boxList li .teams {

    }

    .boxList li .team {
        text-align:left;

        color:#000;
        clear:left;
        line-height:13px;
        height:13px;
    }

    .boxList li .score {
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:right;
        color:#fff;
        float:right;
        display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: That had no affect on the problem.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: is your problem during compatibility mode, during no compatibility mode? both?

Answer (score 0):

The width on your divs is set to 100%, so the div is stretching to 100% width and filling all available horizontal space. You can fix this by applying a fixed width to your divs.

Comment: I can't have a fixed width, because some will have the potential to be longer.  I have a min-width set.  But I did go ahead and remove the 100% width from the .team divs and removed the float.  This would make the width be the width of the content.  It looks fine in all browsers, but same horrible bug in IE7.  

Also, remember that it looks fine with or without the 100% width, as long as I remove the nested .score div.

Comment: I'm starting to think you might actually be better off using <code>display:inline-block</code> on the .team divs (instead of float). Older versions of IE handle inline-block surprisingly well, and it should keep your content expandable without 100% width.